# R-project file does not recognize any of my working directory folders - can't save any of my plots/tables

Tags: r

I need your help! I can't figure out why my R-project file is not recognizing any of the folders in my working directory.

I am working off of a R-project file. I have been working in this file for a long time. Today it decides to have a bunch of problems but one of them is not recognizing any of the folders in my working directory.

I am trying to export a table from the viewer console of R-studio into a JPEG file. I want to export the table through the viewer box using the "export" button into one of the folders located in my working directory but R-studio thinks the "file" does not exist. In the end, I can't save any plots or tables into my working directory folders.

How can I resolve this issue?

Also in case you need it, I am using R-studio ver 2023.06.1 build 524.

All advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Steps I took to attempt to save the table into a JPEG:

1. with the table in the viewer, I click on "export", then "save as image". [Click this link to see what my R-studio window looks like and the "export" button I am using in the viewer box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guyN8.jpg)
2. a window pops up with a preview of my table. I click on "directory" to change the path to save the image into a folder that is located in my working directory. [Click this link to see the pop up window and where I clicked to change the path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFyse.jpg)
3. once I click on the directory, a file explorer window pops up along with another window warning "(file name). This file doesn't exist. Create file?"  [Click this link to see the pop up windows and warning message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGIpP.jpg)

Should I just use a code and leave the "export" button alone? Do I need to set up my working directory a different way to enable R-studio to recognize the folders?

Comment: With questions like this, we generally ask about the working directory: does `getwd()` indicate the directory you think you're working in?

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it states the desired directory so I am not sure why I am having this problem.